# SparkR vs plain scala regarding parallel performance

Tags: c, apache-spark, sparkr

When the data is trimmed down using spark-SQL and grouping functionality that it fits into RAM of a single node is it more useful (regarding **performance**) to run computations using **native spark** (e.g. scala) code or is it advisable to use **plain sparkR** code which relies on performing the calculation **in C**

Which approach parallelizes better: There will be multiple groups and not all will be located on a single machine.

Comment: sparkr will still initiate a jvm so computations are not actually made in C at some level. Plus this question is too broad. You need to read the how to ask questions section on stackoverflow. This is not the first time I flag you for being off-topic.

Comment: sorry for being off topic. How would you suggest to narrow it down to fit better? As the main question for me is: is it worth the effort rewriting R code for scala because of better parallel performance

Comment: you might want to read [this](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-Python-so-popular-in-machine-learning/answer/Elias-Abou-Haydar?srid=agpP)

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I will evaluate both options and possibly re-write it in scala.

Comment: and please read on how to ask question and what question are in the scope of SO. I will be starting to downvote other wise